# Create Column in Pandas from Aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe 'xyz' and I want to create a new column based on a simple calculation, but when I run the code below, the result is NaN.

xyz =

```
   account_id    date    
0    123        2016-01-01
1    124        2016-01-01
2    125        2016-01-01
3    126        2016-01-01
4    123        2016-01-02
5    124        2016-01-02
6    125        2016-01-02
7    126        2016-01-02
```

New column I want to create: number of days where I have data per account_id.

Code I'm executing:

```
xyz['new_column'] = xyz.groupby('account_id').date.nunique()
```

Result I get:

```
   account_id    date         new_column
0    123        2016-01-01      NaN
1    124        2016-01-01      NaN
2    125        2016-01-01      NaN
3    126        2016-01-01      NaN
4    123        2016-01-02      NaN
5    124        2016-01-02      NaN
6    125        2016-01-02      NaN
7    126        2016-01-02      NaN
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation):

```
xyz['new_column'] = xyz.groupby('account_id').date.transform('nunique')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks, @Julien Spronck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate solution:

```
xyz['new_column'] = xyz.date.map(dict(xyz.date.value_counts()))
```

Comment: Thanks, @AlexG. I ran this but it counted all instances of the date. Apologies if I worded confusingly. My desired outcome is to have counts of account_id per date, but I switched out 'date' with 'account_id' and got the outcome I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Oops that is my fault. Cheers